# break and continue doesn't work in Java

Tags: java, break

I made this program which reverses a string. It can be done in two ways. so I want to ask user the preferred method. for getting out of the `if else` I use break keyword followed by a label for each choice.

This program works fine without break and label but it gives me errors when using break.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ReverseString {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        System.out.println("Choose a method:");
        Scanner ch = new Scanner(System.in);

        int choice = ch.nextInt();

        if (choice == 1)
        {
            break first;
        }
        else
        {
            break second;
        }

        first:

        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.print("Enter a string to reverse:");

        String original = in.nextLine();

        String reverse = "";
        int i, length = original.length();

        for (i=length-1; i>=0; i--)
        {
            reverse = reverse + original.charAt(i);
        }

        System.out.println(reverse);


        second:

        StringBuilder rev = new StringBuilder(in.nextLine());

        String revc = rev.reverse().toString();

        System.out.println(revc);


    }

}
```

and errors:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems: 
    Syntax error, insert ":: IdentifierOrNew" to complete ReferenceExpression
    Syntax error, insert "AssignmentOperator Expression" to complete Assignment
    Syntax error, insert ";" to complete Statement
    Scanner cannot be resolved to a variable
    in cannot be resolved to a variable
    in cannot be resolved
    Syntax error, insert ":: IdentifierOrNew" to complete ReferenceExpression
    Syntax error, insert "AssignmentOperator Expression" to complete Assignment
    Syntax error, insert ";" to complete Statement
    StringBuilder cannot be resolved to a variable
    rev cannot be resolved to a variable
    in cannot be resolved
    rev cannot be resolved

    at welcome.ReverseString.main(ReverseString.java:25)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You *can* use `break` in if statements but you have to label the blocks. See this example:

```
if (choice == 1) first: {
    // ...
    break first;
    // ...
} else second: {
    // ...
    break second;
    // ...
}
```

However, you **can't** use `break` the way you're trying to use it.

Instead I suggest you structure your program as follows:

```
if (choice == 1) {
    // Code for choice 1
} else {
    // Code for choice 2
}
```

or, even better, split up the code in smaller methods and do

```
if (choice == 1) {
    method1();
} else {
    method2();
}
```

Answer (score 6):

In Java, `break` (and `continue`) are primarily for use in loops, and `break` also has a role in `switch`. You can use `break` to break out of a labelled block, but it frankly doesn't make much sense to do that with an `if` statement. (Details in [JLS §14.15](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.15).)

Instead of trying to use what is effectively "goto", put the two methods of reversing into *methods*, and then call the appropriate method from the blocks connected to your `if` and `else` (where you currently have `break`).

Answer (score 0):

The way you are using break is wrong and it's a compilation problem I see. You are using `break` in a `if` block. `break` are used in a loop - `while` or `for` to skip the renaming iteration.

Here you can use goto with a label. But goto is not a recommended way to organize the flow of a program. Better you can change the flow of your program. And by the way don't tell break is not working in java :), it's being used and tested thousands of time.

Hope it will Help.
Thanks a lot